# Как создать свой список в Java?

Tags: list, java

Всем привет, как можно создать список на Java свой, не используя библиотеку класса List?

Подскажите пожалуйста, буду благодарен.

Comment: можно просто массив создать

Comment: посмотрите аналогичный вопрос про стэк в java. Там есть ответ с ссылкой на исходники. Собственно [вот](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/LinkedList.java.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написать свою реализацию интерфейса java.util.List<T>

Comment: хм, понял, спасибо.

Comment: если не подходит готовый интерфейс, можно написать свой